# how to call the feature file with parameters from another feature file conditionally

Tags: testing, karate

how to call the feature file with parameters from another feature file conditionally.
I need to call the other feature file only when the length of the array(associatedRules is array type) is greater than 0.

I tried below approach but unable to pass the parameters {"username":'shreyansh'} and get the below error.
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:120 Expected ; but found {
if (associatedRules.length > 0) karate.call('classpath:Validation/Data/Features/associate-rule.feature') {"username":'shreyansh'}

```
* if (associatedRules.length > 0) karate.call('classpath:ValidationStore/Datapoints/Features/associate-tcr-rule.feature') {"username":'shreyansh'}
```

I do not want to call the feature when the associatedRules length is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `karate.call()` it is JS, so you have to stick to JS rules. Try this:

```
* if (associatedRules.length > 0) karate.call('classpath:ValidationStore/Datapoints/Features/associate-tcr-rule.feature', {username:'shreyansh'})
```

So `karate.call()` is a JS function and it takes a second argument for the call-arg or parameter.

Also refer this part of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked. This is exactly what I needed. I will go through https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read